# Producing multiple frequency tables at once in R

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have a dataframe of different kind of variables (numeric, character, factor) on the columns which I would liko to summarise at once. I have an ID column to be counted according to the levels of the other columns.

Every column has different levels if they are character or factor and I would like to know the frequency of the IDs for each level. In addition if the column is numeric I would like to have returned summary statistics such as mean, sd, and quantiles.

Ideally I would do this with `dplyr` with `group_by()` and `summarise()` functions but it requires me to group each column at a time and then specify whether I want it counted with `n()` or whether I want summary statistics because of being numeric.
In `SAS` there is a command known as `PROC FREQ` which I am trying to replicate.

```
df<-
  data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  Age = c(20, 30, 45, 60, 70, 18),
  Car = c("Zum", "Yat", "Zum", "Zum", "Yat", "Rel"),
  Side = c("Left", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right")
)
```

Result:

```
 df %>% group_by(Car) %>% summarise(n = n())
 df %>% group_by(Side) %>% summarise(n = n())
 df %>% summarise(mean = mean(Age))
```

I would like to obtain this result in a single output and for many variables. My real df contains tens of columns which should be either grouping variables or not depending on their nature. In addition the `ID` could be even repeated with the same values for the observations to be summarised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function to take action based on it's class. Here, we calculate mean if class of the column is numeric or else perform `count` of unique values in the column.

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map(names(df)[-1], function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(df[[x]])) df %>% summarise(mean = mean(.data[[x]]))
  else df %>% count(.data[[x]])
})

#[[1]]
#  mean
#1 40.5

#[[2]]
#  Car n
#1 Rel 1
#2 Yat 2
#3 Zum 3

#[[3]]
#   Side n
#1  Left 3
#2 Right 3
```